# Relation between $L^{\infty}$ norm of the gradient and Lipschitz constant

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lipschitz-functions

Let $\Omega$ be an open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $u\colon\Omega\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function. By Rademacher Theorem I know that $u$ is differentiable almost everywhere in $\Omega$. Now, my book says that from this fact, it follows that
$$
\|Du\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq\operatorname{Lip}(u, \Omega),\qquad (\star)
$$
where $\operatorname{Lip}(u, \Omega)$ is the Lipschitz constant of $u$ in $\Omega$. I do not understand why inequality $(\star)$ holds. Can someone help me?

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $L:=\text{Lip}(u,\Omega)$. If the inequality were false, then there would exist $x\in \Omega$ such that $|Du(x)|\geq L+\varepsilon$, for some $\varepsilon > 0 $. In particular, $Du(x)\neq 0$. By definition of $Du$, there is $\delta >0$ such that for all $0<t\leq \delta $, $|h|=1$ we have
$$\left|\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}-Du(x)\cdot h\right|\leq \varepsilon/2 $$
In particular, 
$$\left|\frac{f(x+th)-f(x)}{t}\right|\geq |Du(x)\cdot h|-\varepsilon/2 $$
now choose $h=\frac{Du(x)}{|Du(x)|}$ (recall that $Du(x)\neq 0$). Then we get
$$\left|f(x+th)-f(x)\right|\geq (|Du(x)|-\varepsilon/2)t\geq (L+\varepsilon/2)t $$

which contradicts the fact that $L$ is the Lipschitz constant (recall that $|h|=1$).

Comment: Thank You for your attempt. Maybe there is another way to prove the inequality. Indeed, where exists, $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}=\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\frac{u(x+te_i)-u(x)}{t}$, from which it follows that $\|Du\|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}\leq\operatorname{Lip}(u, \Omega)$. Is it right?

Comment: As $|Du|$ we choose $|Du|=\max_{i=1,\ldots,n}|u_{x_i}|$, which is equivalent to the Euclidean norm

Comment: Yes, that should be the 'limit version' of my proof, I basically made that limit explicit with $\varepsilon$s and $\delta$s, aside from that nothing is different I would say. For sure taking the limit directly as you did is more efficient though.

Comment: Also I took the limit from an arbitrary direction, but since the norm of the gradient (provided it exists, and we know it does) only depends on the partial derivatives alongside the axes, your approach is equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Please, see the book "Measure theory and fine properties of functions": p155, theorem 4.5, which states:

$f$ is locally Lipschitz $\iff$ $f \in W^{1,\infty}_{\text{loc}}$

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1867146)

Comment: I did not find it. Could you tell me what edition you have?

Comment: Also, do you know if it also holds $f$ lipschiz if and only if $f \in W^{1,\infty}$?

Comment: Found: this was actually in the 2nd edition of the book. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: A Lipschitz function f could be unbounded in the whole space, that is, the L infinity norm could be infinity. Hence f may not belong to W^{1,\infty}. For example, f(x)=|x|.